# match a input string with string

Tags: objective-c

I've a method which takes in phonenumber and returns BOOL based on the condition if that phonenumber is in NSMutableDictionary or not.

This is the structure of dictionary

key              value

cellphone        1234567890

workphone        2345678910

homephone        4252433718

How can I check if that phonenumber is in the dictionary?

I tried doesContain but it's always returning NO even if the number is in dictionary.

Comment: `return [dict allKeysForObject:phoneNumber].count > 0;`

Comment: this is working, but would you please explain ">0"

Comment: @userXXX If you don't know what `> 0` means, then you should yet be reading a beginners' C book instead of already making iOS apps...

Comment: oh wow, sorry about that, my brain is so worked up...

Comment: @userXXX np, I just don't feel like explaining it when it's trivial to search for :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it.

```
- (BOOL) hasNumber:(NSString *) phoneNumber
{ 
   return [[phoneNumbers allValues] containsObject:phoneNumber];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSNumber *object = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1234567890];

if ([dictionary allKeysForObject:object] count] > 0) {
    NSLog(@"The number is in dictionary.");
} else {
    NSLog(@"The number is not there in dictionary.");
}
```

Comment: phonenumber is value for keys like cellphone, workphone, homephone

Answer (score 0):

check this.. I'm not sure if this is what you want

```
NSDictionary *dictionary =  @{@"workhome":@(123123),@"homephone":@(456456)};

if (dictionary[@"workhome"] != nil)
{
    //the key "workhome" has something
}

if ([[dictionary allValues] containsObject:@(123123)])
{
    //the user has this number
    NSArray *key = [dictionary allKeysForObject:@(123123)];
    if (key.count > 0)
    {
        //now you have all keys for this object.
    }
}
```